# Toggle Button not updating

Tags: java, android

code is working but problem is when i switch on/off wifi from setting at that time toggle is not updating  like if toggle button showing on and wifiis  also on but if i switch off wifi from setting then this toggle still showing on how to  update toggle ?
          Edit final code sry 1st was typo :(

```
   final WifiManager wifi =  (WifiManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);    
IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter();
iFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
//registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, itFilter);
Intent batteryStatu = getActivity().registerReceiver(null, iFilter);
  final Switch wi = (Switch) av.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
      wi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (wi.isChecked())
            {
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);

        }
            else {
                wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
            }   ;
        }
    });
```

Comment: you have 2 ToggleButtons and for onCheckedChangeListener using the one that is not comming from your layout

Comment: Could you post your xml layout associated with this activity? Thanks

Comment: I have only one button

Comment: Can any one post full code

Comment: @user2455050 you have two ToggleButtons - 1. tButton 2. Button and then you assign listener to a button that does not have an instance - tButton (it does not appear on your screen). ρяσѕρєя K posted the full code

Comment: see, you should either create a ToggleButton in code: ToggleButtons tb = new ToggleButtons(this); or in xml: ToggleButton Button = (ToggleButton) av.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

Comment: it was typo Button = (ToggleButton) av.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
 is tbutton  = (ToggleButton) av.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

Comment: @user2455050 change the original question and get rid of all typos then

Comment: but toggle is not changing when i am doing changes from setting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be notified by the system if the wifi changed, you need a BroadCastReceiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class WifiStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private static final String TAG = "MyNetworkStateReceiver";

        public  static final String ACTION_WIFI_CONNEXION_CHANGED = WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();

            Log.d(TAG, "action=" + action);

            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIFI_CONNEXION_CHANGED)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Connexion changed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED, false)) {
                    // do stuff
                    Log.d(TAG, "WIFI state connected! :)");
                } else {
                    // wifi connection was lost
                    Log.d(TAG, "WIFI state disconnected! :(");
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

afterward, you need to register your receiver in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     //init your UI
     //......
    wifiReceiver = new WifiStateReceiver();
    registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiStateReceiver.ACTION_WIFI_CONNEXION_CHANGED));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(wifiReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And don't foget permmissions in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

And Finally update your UI in onReceive() method from your BrodcastReceiver! :)